# Random forest regression in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, random-forest

I want to predict continuous response variable using random forest regression in Google Earth Engine (GEE), but I can't find it, at least in docs.

Are there any known sources (e.g., internal and external packages) implementing random forest regressor directly in GEE?

Comment: https://fsapps.nwcg.gov/gtac/CourseDownloads/Training/Remote_Sensing/DigitalSoilMapping_EarthEngine_NRCS/01_Exercises/04.2_DigitalSoilMappinginEarthEngine_RandomForestRegression.docx

Comment: Thanks for your great source.